# 0.0.ToString(".####") returns empty string

Tags: c#, .net, string-formatting

Why `0.0.ToString(".####")` returns empty string but not `0`? What format string should I use for proper output?

Comment: What would you expect the output to be in that case?  What about a number >= 1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think about what you're asking - you ask for no required digits *before* the decimal point and up to 4 *optional* significant digits *after* the decimal point.

Since `0.0` has *no* significant digits before or after the decimal, it returns nothing.

To give you the proper format string we need the expected output in each of the following cases:

- A number >= 1
- A number between 0 and 1 (exclusive)
- 0

Note that you can use [*section separators*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#SectionSeparator) to explicitly say how you want to format positive numbers, negative numbers, and 0:

```
0.0.ToString(".####;-.####;0")   // returns "0"
```

The nice thing about using section separators (versus explicitly checking for 0) is that it will use the "0" format specifier *if the formatted string would be equivalent to 0*.

For example,

```
(-0.0000001).ToString(".####;-.####;0")
```

will return `"0"` since the small negative number will be rounded to four decimals based on your format specification.

Answer (score 6):

To always show the digit for the 1s position, then you need to specify a zero in the string format specifier for that digit. See the following:

```
// outputs "0"
0.0.ToString("0.####")
```

If you want to show extra decimal places, even if they are zero, then you can also use zeros to do that:

```
// outputs "5.1000"
(5.1).ToString("0.0000")
```

For more information see:
[Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

If you want to show only the 1s position for the number zero.. then do this:

```
String text = (number == 0) ? "0" : number.ToString(".####");
```

Comment: It's working for 0.0, but not working for 0.5 (0.5 instead of .5)

Comment: So you are wanting to omit the 1s position on a number except zero? You'll need an if condition then

Comment: `0.5.ToString(".000")` returns .500 for me.

Comment: @KvanTTT See my edit, you'll just have to add a condition on zero